# How can I switch one user to another in FreeBSD?

Tags: freebsd, users

How can I switch one user to another in FreeBSD?

For examples, I am user david now and I want to change to user Bob.
This is a personal OS for my study. not a server.
I searched it, but only got sites about how to create new user.

Answer (score 8):

You have many options, including `su`, `login`, `ssh`, and `sudo`.

The easiest way is to run [su](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=su&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD+8.2-RELEASE&format=html), e.g.

```
$ su otheruser
```

or

```
$ su - otheruser
```

The first one sets your user to `otheruser`.

The second one sets you user to `otheruser` and sources otheruser's login scripts (e.g. `.profile` for `sh` or `.login` for `csh`), to make it seem like you've logged in as that user.

If `otheruser` is `root` (or is missing, which also means `root`), then you will need to be in the `wheel` group, as per the man page:

> by default  only users in the `wheel` group can switch to UID 0 (`root`).

Another way is [login](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=login&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD+8.2-RELEASE&format=html), e.g.

```
$ login
login: otheruser
Password:
```

Or, if you are running sshd, you could use [ssh](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=ssh&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD+8.2-RELEASE&format=html), e.g.

```
$ ssh otheruser@localhost
```

Or you could install [sudo](http://www.freshports.org/security/sudo/) using [ports](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/handbook/ports.html).

```
# cd /usr/ports/security/sudo
# make && make install
```

or [packages](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/handbook/packages-using.html)

```
# pkg_add -r sudo
```

See the [sudo man page](http://www.gratisoft.us/sudo/man/1.8.0/sudo.man.html) for details of how to run it.

Answer (score 1):

`su` can be used for this purpose. If you want to become user `bob` you would type:

```
su bob
```

`su` will then ask for a password, which is `bob`'s password, not yours. When invoked without arguments it tries to become superuser (same as `su root`). You may have to add your user account to the `wheel` group, or [change some configuration](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/freebsd-becoming-super-user-su-or-enabling-su-access-to-user.html) so that the normal user can use `su`.

I usually do:

```
sudo su - bob
```

so I won't need to know the password of the other user (Note: I'm a Linux user and I'm not sure how different BSD is).

Comment: wheel is only required to su to root.

Comment: Why `sudo su - bob` instead of just `sudo -s -u bob`?

Comment: Hmm I guess it's just a habit :)